# dont share VPN with Mobile Hotspot windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, hotspot

I enable Mobile Hotspot in Windows 10 and connect to my VPN-PPTP and share VPN with connection (Local Area Connection* 3) Mobile Hotspot.

now I connecting with my Phone to my Mobile Hotspot(share by windows 10) but I can't open the website if I disconnect from VPN my phone network working.

how to fix this problem. I need to share my internet laptop with a VPN.

don't work for me:
[How to share a VPN connection over WiFi on Windows 10](https://support.cyberghostvpn.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002698345-How-to-share-a-VPN-connection-over-Wi-Fi-on-Windows-10)

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwUK0.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your connection is bridged to win10 adaptor , your phone can NOT use vpn connection. also setting pptp type DOES'NT make a new network adaptor.  
 make sure you have configured your network correctly. for instance if NAT is selected in your mobile hotspot setting.
 If it doesn't work **change your VPN type**, for example cisco anyconnect is a great choice. whole streams are through this VPN (is't a whole new network adaptor)

Comment: my laptop with LAN (modem 4G to laptop), connect to the internet and share laptop internet with Hotspot in windows 10. I connect from my phone to my laptop hotspots. I have purevpn and express VPN

Comment: @user3770797 As I said, try setting in your hotspot app (NAT enabled) or change your VPN protocol to ipsec or ssl .